# Trim a possible prefix of a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have `String str`, from which I want to extract the sub-string excluding a possible prefix `"abc"`.

**The first solution that comes to mind is:**

```
if (str.startsWith("abc"))
    return str.substring("abc".length());
return str;
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a "cleaner" way to do it using `split` and a regular expression for an `"abc"` **prefix**?
2. If yes, is it less efficient than the method above (because it searches "throughout" the string)?
3. If yes, is there any better way of doing it (where "better way" = clean and efficient solution)?

Please note that the `"abc"` prefix may appear elsewhere in the string, and should not be removed.

Thanks

Comment: Concerns about "efficiency" are rather silly here, unless you're attempting to do this millions of times per X and that's the bottleneck. You code, as is, *reads well and conveys the intent*.

Answer (score 79):

Shorter than above code will be this line:

```
return str.replaceFirst("^abc", "");
```

But in terms of performance I guess there wont be any substantial difference between 2 codes. One uses regex and one doesn't use regex but does search and substring.

Comment: If that's the case, then this solution will **not** work for me.

Comment: What is your expected output for different positions of `"abc"`?

Comment: I have edited regex slightly to make sure `abc` is stripped off from beginning only otherwise string will remain unchanged.

Comment: Will `replaceFirst` do a "thorough search", or will it stop immediately due to the `'^'`?

Comment: It will stop immediately if string doesn't start with `abc` due to presence of anchor `^`

Answer (score 14):

Using `String.replaceFirst` with `^abc` (to match leading `abc`)

```
"abcdef".replaceFirst("^abc", "")     // => "def"
"123456".replaceFirst("^abc", "")     // => "123456"
"123abc456".replaceFirst("^abc", "")  // => "123abc456"
```

Comment: What about `"123abc456".replaceFirst("^abc", "")`?

Comment: Will `replaceFirst` do a "thorough search", or will it stop immediately due to the `'^'`?

Comment: @barakmanos, `^` matches only at the beginning of the input string. I didn't examine the `replaceFirst`; I'm not sure it will do thorough search, but I guess not.

Answer (score 11):

A regex-free solution (I needed this because the string I'm removing is configurable and contains backslashes, which need escaping for literal use in a regex):

Apache Commons Lang [`StringUtils.removeStart(str, remove)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeStart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) will remove `remove` from the start of `str` using `String.startsWith` and `String.substring`.

The [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java) of the method is informative:

```
public static String removeStart(final String str, final String remove) {
    if (isEmpty(str) || isEmpty(remove)) {
        return str;
    }
    if (str.startsWith(remove)){
        return str.substring(remove.length());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: My prefix contains underscores and I really HATE to use double backslashes to escape. First backslash for the Java compiler, second backslash for the Regexp compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("^abc", "");
```

Comment: Will this "cut off" **only** the prefix `"abc"`, if such one exists?

Comment: ^ makes it match only abc at the begining

Answer (score 1):

1. Using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) can do this, but it's not better solution. Actually it'll be vague and I wouldn't recommend using it for that purpose.
2. Don't waste time about efficiency in this case, it's not significant, focus on logic and clarity. But note that working with regex is usually slower because it involves additional operations so you might want to keep `startsWith`.
3. Your approach is fine, if you want to check if the String begins with "abc", [`String#startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) was designed for that.

---

You can easily measure the time that takes a code to run. Here what you can do:

Create a big loop, inside it you can append the counter of it to some dummy String in order to simulate the Strings you want to check, then try to have `startsWith` once, and `replaceAll` after:

```
for(int i = 0;i<900000;i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
    sb.append(i);
    if(sb.toString().startsWith("abc")) { ... } 
}
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println(time); //Prints ~130
```

---

```
for(int i = 0;i<900000;i++){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
   sb.append(i);
   sb.toString().replaceAll("^abc", "");        
}
long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println(time);  //Prints ~730
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not describe the entire context in which I am using this method, so I don't think that you can claim that I shouldn't "waste time about efficiency in this case".

Comment: Several answers here are suggesting `str.replaceFirst("^abc", "")`. Would that be equivalently efficient?

Comment: @barakmanos For how many Strings are you planning to do that?

Comment: 1,000,000,000,000 (needed to add a few more 0s in order to add this comment, but still quite a few)

Comment: Thank you `ᴍaroun`. It should be `replaceFirst` and not `replaceAll`. In addition, please note that any use of `startsWith(...)` must be followed by `substring(...)` and `length()`, which you did not take into account in your test above. I'm gonna post a separate question on the performance of `replaceFirst` and see the answers (although I will probably use your suggestion above in order to empirically assert this).

Comment: @barakmanos Indeed. You might want to run a full test with the exact code and measure the times. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance you can improve `str.replaceFirst("^abc", "")` solution by using same pre-compiled prefix `Pattern` for matching multiple strings.

```
final Pattern prefix = Pattern.compile("^abc"); // Could be static constant etc
for ... {
    final String result = prefix.matcher(str).replaceFirst("");
}
```

I guess the difference will be noticeable if you stripping the same prefix from a lot of strings.

Answer (score -1):

As far as efficiency is concerned you may use `StringBuilder` where you have multiple operations on one string such as substring then, finding index, then substring etc etc.

---

Where cleanliness/efficiency is concerned, `StringUtils (Apache Commons Lang)` can be used.

Hope it helps.