# Is Haskell-style pattern matching on Scala Strings possible?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I just curious.

I try to do pattern matching strings in Scala with Haskell way (as list of chars)

As an example, this function that remove first "/" character in string:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def stringToChars(s: String): List[Char] = s.toCharArray.toList

implicit def charsToString(a: List[Char]): String = a.mkString

def filterFirstSlash: Function[List[Char], String] = {
  case Nil => ""
  case '/' :: Nil => ""
  case '/' :: xs => xs
  case xs => xs
}
```

usage:

```
println(filterFirstSlash("/test"))
```

Can I remove the leading slash using patter-matching? Is this good to do it in this way?

**upd**

this will remove all entries in head and tail:

```
def removeAllSlashes: Function[List[Char], String] = {
    case Nil => ""
    case '/' :: xs => removeAllSlashes(xs)
    case xs :+ '/' => removeAllSlashes(xs)
    case xs => xs
}
```

this will remove first entries only:

```
def removeFirstSlash: Function[List[Char], String] = {
    case Nil => ""
    case ('/' :: xs) :+ '/' => xs
    case '/' :: xs => xs
    case xs :+ '/' => xs
    case xs => xs
}
```

p.s.
Do not take it so seriously.
This is just for fun.
Thanks to everyone involved in the discussion.

Comment: maybe you can use `replaceFirst` and pass regex `^\\/`..Also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545933/trim-a-possible-prefix-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I rolled it back, sorry. I maybe would agree if you *added* `[regex]` tag, because this seems like one appropriate solution in this case. But I'm against removing `pattern-matching`, since "Why doesn't pattern matching work here" seems to be an important part of the question.

Comment: I know about regex. This is not about it. My curiosity was - is it possible do in haskell way? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, technically:

```
def filterFirstSlash(s: String) = {
  case '/' +: xs => xs
  case xs => xs
}
```

Of course, isn't as efficient as the same code for a linked list, since `+:` copies the whole string every time, so you wouldn't want to use this to recursively pick apart strings.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not a good way to do it. `String`s are not list of chars. On the JVM, Strings are rather immutable arrays of UTF-16 code units. They have nothing to do with linked lists. Your `filterFirstSlash` will always ignore the first three cases, and always return the input unchanged.

To drop the slash, you could do something like this:

```
"////abcd".dropWhile(_ == '/')  // returns `"abcd"`
```

or

```
"/abcd".replaceAll("^/", "")
```

or

```
((s: String) => if (s startsWith "/") s.tail else s )("/abcd")
```

or maybe, if you really insist on pattern-matching, then you can use precompiled regex-patterns to match the leading slash and the rest of the string:

```
val Rgx = "^/(.*)$".r
"/abcd" match { case Rgx(s) => s; case s => s }      // evaluates to `"abcd"`
```

Comment: @HoTicE Then I can highly recommend to try it out in the repl: `"abcd".tail == "bcd"`. It simply drops the first char. Same as `s.substring(1)`.

Comment: @airudah What "this"? The `dropWhile`? It will remove all leading slashes. I assumed that there is at most one. If it's crucial that at most one slash is removed, then there are the other three solutions that do just that.

Comment: Maybe I understood wrong but I thought he wanted the first `/` in the tail removed, not every `/`..

Comment: @airudah You don't have to speculate: just take the function `def filterFirstSlash = (s: String) => s.toList match { case Nil => ""; case '/' :: xs => xs.mkString; case xs => xs.mkString }` and try out what it does on few examples, if you don't see it from the code directly.

Comment: No no, ofc I know it works as designed...  Ahh, Never mind, the question was a bit confusing. I've corrected the wording

Comment: @airudah The wording was indeed strange, I modified it so it agrees with the code.